# Set a Tab from an activity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a TabActivity and inside 5 tabs with 5 activities each one. I want to set one of my tabs but not from the TabActivity(clicking on the tab on the top) but from an activity of any tab, for example clicking on a button of activity 3(which is asociated with the 3rd tab).
In my TabActivity there is a variable `mTabhost`, which I can use to set the selected tab with

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);//home
```

I guess I need access to that variable from Activity1-2-3-4, and doing that variable static doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a `MyTabActivity` as `TabActivity`, which hosts 5 `Activity`(ies).
If you want to change the Tabs inside `SecondActivity`, you would write the code something like this.

```
MyTabActivity myTabs = (MyTabActivity) this.getParent();
```

Here you have your MyTabActvity
you can change the tabs like:

```
myTabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save this mHost var instance in singleton class say Utility class . Then access particular var from Utility Class in different activity and set it accordingly. It works. I 've used it in my several projects.