# android go back to a specific tab

Tags: android, sqlite

ShareMarketActivity.java this handles the tabs, Tab1, Tab2, Tab3.java files..... which on load it load the 1st tab

in Tab3 (portfolio) when u click on the company it moves to another window, what i want to do is,when u click back button on the new window... it should again load the tabs and it moves to the Tab3.

```
 back.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ShareMarketActivity"));
                }

            });
```

So this will load the tabs again and show the tab1 as the starting tab. Not the Tab3. what i want is... ** load the ShateMarketActivity and straight away moves to tab3 ** ( in the 1st load i want Tab1 to be the 1st load not tab3)

Comment: [Hava a look at answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532455/set-a-tab-from-an-activity/6532564#6532564)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setCurrentTab method of the tab host.

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is listed briefly below. I am not putting any code though but it should be straightforward.

1. When you are navigating to a new window do not navigate through the child activities that reside in the TAB Host. Call getParent() and then start new Activity from the TabActivity which is the Parent.
2. Make the Tab launchmode in manifest as SingleTask.
3. You can not capture the result of the Activity in onActivityResult in TabHost and then call the child Activity to propogate the result by using getCurrentActivity()

The reason for the behavior you see is that Tabs are actually an ActivityGroup with multiple activities embedded in them for each TAB. Once you call a new Activity from any of the child Activity and then come back the Activity stack loses the Activity Group and lists the calling activity as parent and hence you just see TAB3 activity as the only activity.

Let me know if this does not help.